# remove second comma from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an string as:

```
0123456789,, 0987654213 ,, 0987334213,, ......
```

How can I convert this into

```
0123456789, 0987654213, 0987334213, ......
```

i.e I want to remove the second comma

Comment: What happened when you tried to replace all ",," instances with ","? Surely you looked into string.replace methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: The second pair of commas is proceeded by a space in the input; that space is not in the output: typo or part of the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it very simply, like this using regex.

```
var str = "0123456789,,0987654213,,0987334213,,,,,9874578";
str=str.replace(/,*,/g,',');
console.log(str)
```

Comment: @enhzflep  Thanks.

Comment: Thank for your answer But the best Pattern for this goal is :
`replace(/,*,/g,',');` ===> `replace(/,+/g,',');`

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "0123456789,, 0987654213 ,, 0987334213,, ......"
console.log(str.replace(/\,+/g,","));
```

Comment: That will reduce any sequence of two *or more* commas to one. Which isn't quite the requirement...

Comment: Isn't it incorrect? It will replace the first occurrence of `,,` in `str`

Comment: The code is updated the above comment is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace() method with regular expression with g flag to replace all instances ',,' with ',':

```
str.replace(/,,/g, ",");
```

Here's a simple example

```js
var str = '0123456789,, 0987654213 ,, 0987334213';
str = str.replace(/,,/g, ",");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all occurrences of consecutive commas with a single comma:

```
str.replace(/,+/g, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "0123456789,, 0987654213 ,, 0987334213,,"
str = str.split(",,").join(",")
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a replace method for String.
You can replace ',,' with a ','.

An example:

```
var str = "0123456789,, 0987654213,, 0987334213,"; 
var newStr = str.replace(/,,/g,','));
```

The output:

```
0123456789, 0987654213, 0987334213,
```